# DeprecationWarning: gdal.py was placed in a namespace, it is now available as osgeo.gdal

Tags: python, warnings, gdal, osgeo, pyqgis

I have a problem with my script. I would like to use a package that allows me to use the qgis software directly in my code. This package is called qgis.core. I had some trouble installing it, but it seems to be done. The problem now is that when I run my script that allows me to do the treatments I want I get an error message. I'll put you under the script and the error.
If anyone can help me, thank you.

The script :

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination
import processing

class Modle(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination('Fuzzy', 'fuzzy', createByDefault=True, defaultValue='MYPATH\Fuzzy.sdat'))

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
    # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
    # overall progress through the model
    feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
    results = {}
    outputs = {}

    # Fuzzify
    alg_params = {
        'A': 0.3,
        'AUTOFIT     ': False,
        'B': 0.7,
        'C': 0,
        'D': 0,
        'INPUT': 'MYPICTURE.tif',
        'TYPE': 0,
        'OUTPUT': parameters['Fuzzy']
    }
    outputs['Fuzzify'] = processing.run('saga:fuzzify', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['Fuzzy'] = outputs['Fuzzify']['OUTPUT']
    return results

def name(self):
    return 'Modèle'

def displayName(self):
    return 'Modèle'

def group(self):
    return ''

def groupId(self):
    return ''

def createInstance(self):
    return Modle()
```

The return :

```
DeprecationWarning: gdal.py was placed in a namespace, it is now available as osgeo.gdal
  DeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: This is a warning, not an error ... Is the script working as you expect? As to the reason for the warning, one of the modules is likely importing GDAL the deprecated way `import gdal` instead of the recommended way `from osgeo import gdal`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The script is running but the result it is supposed to produce (an image) is not found...In my script I don't import gdal... But qgis is based on gdal I think...

Comment: qgis needs gdal most likely. In any case, the "error" you post here, is not an error. If you don't have your expected result, then there's another issue

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll check the script, any idea of the problem ?

Comment: Hard to say like this, you would need to add any error message and describe what you want to do and what's working or not

Comment: Okay, I have a code that preprocesses sentinel-1 data and it works fine. After these preprocessings, I'd like to make a fuzzy classification with the fuzzify tool available in SAGA and QGIS. I had difficulties to install the qgis.core module but I finally succeeded using conda forge. Since then, I get this warning message, but no error... I even added a print("end") to see if the script was running until the end and it is the case.... However, the pre-processed images are well presented in output but not the fuzzy classification... An idea ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue with `gdal`, but rather with the software you are using.

Comment: A problem with QGIS ? Okay I'll check this.... Thanks !